# Javascript parameters

Tags: javascript

Function without parameters work well, but I would like to make general function to use in different pages. However, now with parameters function do not work.

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function showText(left, right) {
        var textSection = document.getElementById(left);
        textSection.setAttribute("style", "visibility: visible");
       var placeSection = document.getElementById(right);
       placeSection.onmousedown = hideText(left, right); 
    }

    function hideText(left, right) {
        var textSection = document.getElementById(left);
        textSection.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden");
        var placeSection = document.getElementById(right);
        placeSection.onmousedown = showText(left, right);                                           
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**:

```
<h1 align="center">Show Text</h1>
<p align="center">
    <br />
    <br />
    <p onmousedown="showText('menu','click');" id="click">Click Here</p>
    <div id="menu" class="widget" style="visibility: hidden">Hidden Text</div>
</p>
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking or what the current problem is.

Comment: Can you post the source code for the `showText` function? Nothing in the showText or hideText functions seems to be the issue offhand. Also, can you post an example function call and some example markup that it should operate on?

Comment: <h1 align="center">Show Text</h1>

   <p align="center">


    <br /><br />
<p onmousedown="showText('menu','click');" id="click">Click Here</p>

<div id="menu" class="widget" style="visibility: hidden">Hidden Text</div>


   </p>

Comment: "Does not work" suggests that you haven't done further debugging than loading the page and realising it's not displaying the expected output. Even if you've found the code in Google you need to have some general idea of how it works and you at least need to use the console to read error messages.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this line :

```
placeSection.onmousedown = hideText(left, right);
```

You must give a reference to a function in onmousedown. But you are just executing a function and give its result (and the result is `undefined`). You should use an anonymous function :

```
placeSection.onmousedown = function() {
    hideText(left, right); 
};
```

And you should do the same thing in your `hideText` function.

Comment: earlier i read information that if name of the fuction is in event - javascript understand that it is function. With real id it works